# In Inkscape: how to intersect multiple paths so that a silhouette reproduces the colours of the paths?

Tags: inkscape

This may be a very stupid question, but I haven't for the life of me figured it out even after playing around and researching.

Specifically, I am trying to intersect multiple paths of different colours onto a silhouette so that the ultimate intersected silhouette reproduces the colours of the paths.

For example, I have the following intersection of paths (with the blue rectangle being the silhouette):

[image]

And what I want is something like this:

[image]

I tried several permutations of the intersection function, but to no avail.

Comment: Can't you set a clipping path for this?

Comment: Or do Path > Stroke to path on the long line (if that is only a single stroke path), then use the Path > Division operation to cut it with the shapes. The shapes must be on top for that. Then give it the color you want.